# Difference between file tests in Bash

Tags: bash

I am troubleshooting an existing Bash script and in the script it has two tests:

```
if [ ! -s <file_location> ] ; then
   # copy the file to the file_location
   if [ -s <file_location> ] ; then
   # operate on the file
   fi
fi
```

According to the [Bash Tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html), `-s` tests if the file is not of zero size. Would it be better to replace the `! -s` test with a `-e` ? I could understand the second, nested test being a `-s` but the first one looks like it could be replaced with `-e`. What is the advantage here of `! -s` vs `-e`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file exists but is empty, `-e` would pass, but the file would likely be useless. Using `! -s` ensures that the file is present *and* contains useful content.

Comment: Right. But if the file is of zero size, it will still be re-copied, where as it won't be if it is of non-zero size. `-e` would re-copy the file regardless.